# Can't downgrade to Java JDK 8 from version 14 on OSX

Tags: java, java-8, downgrade, java-14

I've followed the [oracle instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) to uninstall Java on OSX. I restart my Mac, and 'java -version' says JDK 14. Then I installed JDK 8.

I've followed many different stack exchange answers to downgrade Java. Every other command indicates I am on Java 8, and the Java control pannel says it is on Java 8 in the JRE settings and Java 8 Update 261 in the update settings.

However, when I do `java -version` it still says I am on Java 14. Nothing I do seems to fix it.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: By the way, as of Java 9, the compiler takes a new `release` flag. We can use the latest JVM while targeting an earlier version of Java. The new flag ensures we cannot use an API added to later versions of Java. The latest versions of Maven and such tools can be configured with this flag, so it is quite convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Here some guide which could help
https://explainjava.com/uninstall-java-macos/

If you plan to support multiple versions I would recommend using `sdk`

```sh
# list all possible java versions
sdk list java

# Install your favourite version
sdk install java <Identifier>

# Set which version you prefer to be default
sdk default java <Idenfifier>
```